# How to prevent that a Boost::Asio timer blocks the return of the io_service::run()?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have the following (minimized) Class handling my server connection:

```
class AsioServer {
protected:
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
public:
    AsioServer() {}

    void add_request() {
        //Adding async requests to the ioService
    }

    void timeout() {
        //Stop all pedning async operations
        ioService.stop();
    }

    void perform() {
        //Set a timer
        boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(ioService);
        timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
        timer.async_wait(std::bind(&AsioServer::timeout, this));

        //Performe all Async operations
        ioService.run();
        ioService.reset();
    }
};
```

My Problem is that the deadline timer prevents the return of `ioService.run()` until it expires. What I want is the the timer is only called when expering and then canceling the async operations, but not act as `work` in the context of the `io_service`. Are there timers not acting as work, or another good way dealing with this situation?

Comment: Run in a separate thread?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Possible, but I think it will be ugly, because in the real code the timeout function does some more things. And calling `ioService.sop()` won't cancel running handlers therefore I would have to use a lot of mutexes, i'd like to avoid.

Comment: `io_service` is the facility that dispatches the timer completion handler (as well as other asio objects handlers) - if `io_service` would exit before that, no one would invoke your `timeout` function!

Comment: @IgorR. Sure, I want the `io_service` to dispatch my completion handler if 5 seconds pass while my IO operation runs. But I don't want to wait 5 Seconds even if my IO operation is finished within one Second. In this case I also don't need the timer completion handler to be called and therefore want ìo_service.run()` to return.

Comment: Ok, so what you need is to *cancel* the timer on i/o completion. If you try to implement async i/o with timeout - cancel the timer in every completion handler and re-reschedule it before any subsequent async operation.

Comment: @IgorR make that comment an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `io_service::run` does not exit (if not stopped explicitly) as long as it has some work - this includes completion handlers of any i/o objects and timers, because `io_service` is solely responsible for dispatching all these handlers.

If you don't want the timer to wait anymore after a socket i/o operation completes - just `cancel()` the timer or re-schedule it, if appropriate. You can find such an approach [in asio examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp).